# Instructions on compiling FFmpeg into static build (.lib files only) for use in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, compilation

So I found [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Using_FFMpeg.aspx) but it seems quite a bit old... So I wonder where to get 100% uptodate instructions on building ffmpeg under windows into static .lib files (for use in C and C++ projects). Point is to get ffmpeg as ONLY lib files not as lib+dll.

So where to get such instructions, can any one provide them?

Answer (score 0):

What issues are you getting?

The following site may have what you need.  It's automated builds of mingw ffmpeg static libraries for win32.

http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/

Here is a wiki link with lots of guides and other info about how to compile ffmpeg on windows.  Also has links to other windows ffmpeg builds.

http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=Links

Comment: If you look closer, the static libraries at that site are not static development libraries.  There are only shared libraries that are available for development there (under shared-dev)